# Passing state props to components in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following react structure

```
<Provider store={ store }>
              <Router>
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/how-to" component={ Help } />
                  <Route path="/start" component={ StartPage } />
                  <Route path="/game" component={ GamePlay } />
                  <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
                </Switch>
              </Router>
        </Provider>
```

There is a child in the `StartPage` component that interacts with a property in the store state

```
    .....
// pickBottle is an action from the store for the state
    <div className="text-center">
                        <button alt={bottleData.name} onClick={ (e) => { self.props.pickBottle(bottleData) } }>{bottleData.name}</button>
                      </div>
    ...

    export default connect(state => ({ bottle: state }), { pickBottle } )(PickerSlides)
```

The component works as expected as the this.props.bottle is set on the click event. However,

When I navigate to the `GamePlay` component which has

....

```
  render() {
    const { store } = this.context;
    console.log(store);

    return (

      <div id="game" className="panel" >
          <section className="row flexbox">
            <header>
              <hgroup>
                <h2 id="tries" className="tries">Tries: <span>{ this.state.tries }</span></h2>
                <h3 className="bottles">Opened:<span id="score" className="opened">{ this.state.bottlesOpened }</span></h3>
              </hgroup>
            </header>
            <article className="row flexbox">

            </article>
            </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// map state to props

const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  console.log('map state ', state );
    return {
        bottle: state,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GamePlay)
```

`console.log('map state', state )` is undefined

Does redux work with components across pages? Do I need to use a localStorage to help redux persist through routes?

How can I pass the state as an updated property of the component via the Route/ Switch components?

Comment: What do you mean with across pages? Are you reloading the page when you go to the GamePlay component? Are you correctly initializing the redux store state?

Comment: @krionz yes I am reloading the page and yes i am initialising the redux store state. Do I need to initialise the state on each component or does <Provider> handle it?

Comment: Actually all you have to do is stop reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably reloading the page. Redux's state is stored in memory, and so when you refresh the page it is lost; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104247/in-redux-where-does-the-state-actually-get-stored). You can use something like [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to store your app's state in local storage, etc.

Comment: Is there some Router option to not reload the page? I'm using the defaults and what  I thought would have happened was that the content would have gotten replaced without having to reload.

Comment: @Kendall It most likely has to do with how you are navigating to the `GamePlay` component. My guess is that you are using an href. Try using `Link` instead, which is part of `react-router-dom`. See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link